# What is the proportion of users on Bicycles.StackExchange who are not on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion

It seems most users on Bicycles.StackExchange came from StackOverflow, so the demographic of users is probably fairly narrow.
Are there any figures on the proportion of users on Bicycles.SE who are also on StackOverflow, or not on StackOverlflow?

A related question is should we be recommending Bicycles.StackExchange to our Local Bike Shop (LBS)? I'll ask that question here [Should we be recommending Bicycles.StackExchange to our Local Bike Shop (LBS)](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/454/should-we-be-recommending-bicycles-stackexchange-to-our-local-bike-shop-lbs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now there are

- 108 registered but not network associated users
- 81 unregistered users
- 1784 registered and associated users

Generally associated means "has other Stack Exchange network accounts".

You can audit this by visiting a few random user pages (on the main site, not here on meta); most of them should have stuff on their accounts tab for other sites.

Comment: An quick way of telling if any of the third group came to the network through this site? I'm gonna guess the other way around is more common?

Comment: Stackexchange has quite a variety of sites, so I guess this doesn't narrow associated users to just tech-types. It is also probably a testament to StackExchange that it's very easy to find and join another site you're interested in. What might be interesting is where you came in first. I came in through StackOverflow, hopefully some biking friends will come in through Bicycles and maybe branch out.

Comment: @Neil If you check their network profile it gives an indication of how long ago they joined a site. Take my network profile as an example, you can see that I joined StackOverflow first http://stackexchange.com/users/3a239130-d1f4-4ec6-b6a0-ef429198cd45?tab=accounts

Comment: A random check of a couple dozen profiles of the newest users shows that most came to Bicycles through other sites. Some through other network sites, the ast majority through SO, and one unaffiliated account.

Comment: Actually, you don't have to go to the network account, although you can. As Jeff mentioned, you just need to go their user page on Bicycles and choose the accounts tab. Here's mine http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/2148/jason-s?tab=accounts

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to answer that without looking at [every single user](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users) and seeing who also has an account on Stack Overflow. This is publicly available information, but a clumsy way to check; there could be a way to do this through stackapps or the data dumps. What is it you're hoping to find out, exactly?

My guess is that roughy half the users here came to the site through another stackexchange site. (I found this through Area 51, and found *that* through SuperUser.)

What about other folks? How did you find this site?

Comment: I came from SO, since I am a software developer. I was interested in Bicycles.SE having a wider demographic than software developers or techies.

Comment: I have about a dozen or more SE sites that I'm part of... I found bicycles through the weekly newsletter program that stackexchange just started.